# PHPUnit Laravel - $suiteClassName is an object

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm trying to test an application I'm making in Laravel 5.4 but when I type the phpunit command on the console I get this error:

> PHP Warning:  is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object
>   given in
>   /Users/nico/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php
>   on line 56
>
> Warning: is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given
>   in
>   /Users/nico/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php
>   on line 56 PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class
>   PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite could not be converted to string in
>   /Users/nico/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php
>   on line 32
>
> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite
>   could not be converted to string in
>   /Users/nico/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php
>   on line 32 ~/code/intranet $ phpunit PHP Warning:  is_dir() expects
>   parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given in
>   /Users/nico/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php
>   on line 56
>
> Warning: is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given
>   in
>   /Users/nico/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php
>   on line 56 PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class
>   PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite could not be converted to string in
>   /Users/nico/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php
>   on line 32
>
> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite
>   could not be converted to string in
>   /Users/nico/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php
>   on line 32 ~/code/intranet $

The parameter to which the error refers to and the $suiteClassName variable that somewhere in the code is transformed into an object instead of a string as supposed

```
public function getTest($suiteClassName, $suiteClassFile = '', $suffixes = '')
    {
        if (\is_dir($suiteClassName) &&
            !\is_file($suiteClassName . '.php') && empty($suiteClassFile)) {
            $facade = new File_Iterator_Facade;
            $files  = $facade->getFilesAsArray(
                $suiteClassName,
                $suffixes
            );

            $suite = new TestSuite($suiteClassName);
            $suite->addTestFiles($files);

            return $suite;
        }
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Not sure what the question is. The error is self-explanatory, so stop passing an object.

Comment: Pass the suiteClassFile name instead of suiteClassName

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys,
The problem is that $suiteClassFile is an empty string and I can not figure out where these two variables are being instantiated.
I do not think I have edited Laravel's vendor directory so everything should be as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you have upgraded your php version to 7.0+ . So you need to fix your composer.json . Use "~6.3" instead of "~5.x" on phpunit option. Version 5.x is working with php 5.4, but it's not working with php 7.0+